# HTML / ASPX pages not validating and not rendering or validating

Tags: html, asp.net, validation, encoding

As a disclaimer, I have read all of the posts regarding this topic and have tried all of the suggestions and still don't seem to be able to get this to work.  So, for purposes of this question, I have created a very simple Master page file and an index file.  The code for the master page is:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="master.master.cs"     Inherits="EckankarInOklahoma.master" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>ECKANKAR in Oklahoma</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The index page's code is as follows:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/master.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="EckankarInOklahoma.index" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    I DON'T GET THIS AT ALL :)
</asp:Content>
```

When I debug through Visual Studio, I get the expected white screen that just says:

I DON'T GET THIS AT ALL :)

But after publishing, uploading to the website via ftp and going to the website, I get nothing but my code.  I have saved the files with encoding but without BOM.  I used Sublime Text editor to ensure I was saving without BOM.  I have published and then uploaded, and I have uploaded without publishing.  All to no avail.  I still get unrendered code.

Additionally, I have tried to validate through W3C Schools and the code will not validate.  [I have 3 errors and 3 warnings](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Feckankarinoklahoma.org%2F1New%2Findex.aspx&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Can someone please advise what I might be doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.  Have a great weekend!

***update 1 = I tried what MarcusVinicius suggested and that did get me closer, but now instead of giving me my code as text, it says :

```
This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!
```

I am unsure of where to go from here.  I published the website as not updatable and the config files are in the root directory.  Any more ideas for me to try?  Again, I appreciate all of the help and suggestions.  :)

Comment: I went to the page http://eckankarinoklahoma.org/1New/index.aspx and inpecting headers from server I could see the "Server:Apache/2.4.23" header is present.  You should be publishing your site to an IIS server,

Comment: Thank you - this gets me one step closer.  I very much appreciate the help.  Now, it is showing up as  --- This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!